# my foreach loop running more than required count

Tags: php, php-5.3

I have three items from my menu. i want to calculate total of each item with different quantity.But my foreach loop is calculating every item with the all 3 quantities instead of one item with its given quantity. please explain me where i had done mistake. here is my code.

```
 <?php
         if(isset($_POST['bill'])){
          //foreach ($_POST['qty'] as $item_quantity) {
                 //$item_qty = $item_quantity;
             //}
          ?>
          <div class="row calc">
            <div class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
              <center><h4>Geektroup Hotels</h4>
              <table class="table table-bordered">
                <thead>
                  <th>Sr #</th>
                  <th>Item Name</th>
                  <th>Item Cost</th>
                  <th>Quantity</th>
                  <th>Amount</th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <?php
                  $count = 0;

                    **foreach ($_POST['item_id'] as $item_id)  {
                    $item_num = $item_id;

                    foreach ($_POST['qty'] as $item_quantity) {
                    $item_qty = $item_quantity;**

                  $bill_query = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE item_id = '$item_num'";
                  $bill_run = mysqli_query($con,$bill_query);
                  if(mysqli_num_rows($bill_run)>0){

                      $bill_row = mysqli_fetch_array($bill_run);

                    $item = $bill_row['item_name'];
                    $item_price = $bill_row['item_cost'];
                    $count = $count+1;

                  ?>
                  <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $count;?></td>
                    <td><p><?php echo $item;?></p></td>
                    <td><p><?php echo $item_price;?></p></td>
                    <td><p><?php echo $item_qty;?></p></td>
                    <td><p><?php echo $amount = $item_price * $item_qty;?></p></td>
                  </tr>
         <?php 

             } 
             } 
             }      
            }
         ?>
         </tbody>
              </table>
              </center>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div><!-- /.container -->
```

Comment: can we see your form html?

Comment: post your array structure

Comment: <form method='POST' action=''>
<div class="form-group">
                    <input type="hidden" name="item_id[]" value="<?php echo $item_no;?>" class="form-control">
                    <input type="number" name="qty[]" value="" class="form-control"  placeholder="enter Quantity here" required>
                  </div>
<center><input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="bill" value="Print Bill"></center>
             <form>

Answer (score -1):

Your html output can't be inside the second foreach loop.

Comment: This is more comment than answer

Comment: if am closing the second foreach loop before html output the quantity which i had given for last item is applying for all the items